# Kubuntu Locale Setting

Tags: kubuntu, locale

I have just installed Kubuntu 16.04 using Asia (Rangoon) Timezone. The calendar and some numbers are showing in Myanmar Language.How can I change these language to English while retaining Rangoon Timezone?